# Not assignable to type 'undefined extends T ? () => CustomEvent<T> : (options: CustomEventInit<T>) => CustomEvent<T>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom-events, custom-events, typescript-types

I am getting the following error by trying to create a CustomEventCreator and help to asociate the event name with the options and the details.

**My code:**

```
export const createCustomEventCreator = <T> (
  eventName: string,
  defaultOptions?: EventInit
): (
  undefined extends T
    ? () => CustomEvent<T>
    : (options: CustomEventInit<T>) => CustomEvent<T>
) => {
  return (options?: CustomEventInit<T>): CustomEvent<T> => {
    return new CustomEvent<T>(eventName, { ...defaultOptions, ...options });
  };
};
```

**The error:**
`TS2322: Type '(options?: CustomEventInit<T> | undefined) => CustomEvent<T>' is not assignable to type 'undefined extends T ? () => CustomEvent<T> : (options: CustomEventInit<T>) => CustomEvent<T>'.`

I think the error is associated with the current deprecation of the event.initEvent(), https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent

And I really don't know how to resolve it.

Thank for reading and helping!

Comment: What version of TS. Doens't happen on 4.8 https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wVYBDGwDCAruhALYCiAbsMjPlrtHALxwA8AKgDQB8cAFACg4cYNVoA5bKWAAuOOigBLZAHMuwuABNgAM2yEANjADyYGEpSoA-PKo0YASWRKYggJTyhIwsh26VYC1REDw-VDgOTRFrAXcWPiISCnEYTh5ouC8Ic0s0eSSYMntaZ1d0+OZE4iKUh3SPBLgAb00sGEIoZAEciytbOELi1LK0jh5PQZrh+vGm1pERds7u5GAAdynkkrGefjEHKRkuFrgAOgv-A2MzPrQTi7PevIiAX3cAbk1Xr5+gA

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir 
    "typescript": "3.8.3"

I have tested in 4.8.4 and you are correct, it works, now I will check how to take this to a newer version.

Comment: I think there was an improvement in conditional types to allow assignment of a value if it is assignable to both branches of a conditional type. This happened in 4.3.